# Could not enable CORS for JAX-RS Web Service

Tags: java, cors, jax-rs

When I invoke my service via Angular2 using `http.post` request, I get

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My JAX-RS service

```
@Override
    @POST
    @Path("/getWsCallReports")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getWsCallReports(Query query) {
        try {
            LOG.info("getWsCallReports called for " + query);
            return Response.status(200)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600").entity(wsCallReportDao.getReports(query)).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }
```

Also I've tried to add simple HTTP filter that defines all necessary headers for all requests

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)  servletResponse;

        // TODO: development only
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
```

but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Just in case, I'm using Java EE 6 and I'm not able to implement `ContainerResponseFilter`. I'm sure that it can be done without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in JAX-RS implementation that is built-in to JBoss EAP 6.2 (RestEasy 2.3.7.final).
Upgrade to JBoss EAP 7.0 has solved the problem.